# Google Maps Javascript Event in iOS UIWebView

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, safari, mobile-safari

I have a UIWebView that loads a web page which consists of an embedded Google Maps map.  I want the iOS app to perform an action as long as the user is panning the Google map.  (I'm using the standard method of bridging between Javascript and Objective-C code--creating an IFrame and picking it up on the other side as a page load--and that part is working fine.)

The problem I'm having is that the Google Maps API running on Safari on the iPhone does not pick up 'pan' events continuously.  It only picks up one event at the very end of panning.  (I figured this out using the iPhone simulator web inspector tool available within Safari.)  Google Maps running in Desktop Safari, in contrast, picks up a continuous stream of events whenever the user pans the map--which is what I want.

Here's the Javascript code which runs differently between mobile and. desktop Safari.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function(){
    console.log("This browser is noticing panning.")
})
```

To summarize, in desktop Safari, it prints continuously during a 'bounds changed' action, while in mobile Safari it only prints once at the end of the action.

Is this an issue with Google Maps or with iOS Safari?  How can I fix it?

**EDIT:** While 'bounds_changed' events are not triggered properly in iOS Safari, a 'drag' event *is* triggered continuously.  Still, however, the bounds (retrieved with `map.getBounds()`) of the map are not updated until after the drag motion is complete, so listening for a 'drag' is not much help if I need the bounds.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the exact same issue on mobile... thank you